# NSPredicate with NSFetchedResultsController get all in data store, but limit a certain match?

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm not sure if this is possible - maybe using subqueries - but, I would like to setup a fetch request that will grab all the entities in a data store matching a certain set of properties. Simple enough, but I would also like to limit the number of objects matching another set of criteria.

I'd prefer to be able to stick with NSFetchedResultscontroller compared to rolling my own array and managing as the FRC is working very well.

I will use an example as this is related to a project I've been working on and would like to not "give too much away". Basic entity example:

Tape

- (string) name
- (relationship) manufacturer
- (bool) isTransparent
- (bool) isEmpty

Code:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Tape"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"manufacturer = %@", manufacturer];
request.predicate = predicate
request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES  selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

NSFetchedResultsController frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:moc sectionNameKeyPath:@"isTransparent" cacheName:nil];
```

The FRC uses name to sort alphabetically and the isTransparent flag to separate the sections (works well).

It's possible to have multiple objects in the store marked with the isEmpty flag; however, when displayed to the user, as any given time, I would like to only display one marked with the isEmpty flag.

So, we may have a store with the following:

- Alpha tape (isEmpty = 0, isTransparent = 1)
- Beta tape  (isEmpty = 0, isTransparent = 0)
- Gamma tape (isEmpty = 1, isTransparent = 1)
- Delta tape (isEmpty = 1, isTransparent = 0)

From the current predicate, we would get a table like this:

- Alpha tape (isEmpty = 0, isTransparent = 1)
- Gamma tape (isEmpty = 1, isTransparent = 1)
- *section break*
- Beta tape (isEmpty = 0, isTransparent = 0)
- Delta tape (isEmpty = 1, isTransparent = 0)

What I'm wondering is if it's possible to get something like this for the table view (with the FRC to match):

- Alpha tape (isEmpty = 0, isTransparent = 1)
- Gamma tape (isEmpty = 1, isTransparent = 1)
- *section break*
- Beta tape (isEmpty = 0, isTransparent = 0)

Whereby the table view is sectioned by the isTransparent flag, but only displays one object marked with the isEmpty flag.

Hoping the following additional code will help. This is how I might do this using arrays (note quick and dirty):

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Tape"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"manufacturer = %@", manufacturer];
request.predicate = predicate
request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES  selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

BOOL foundEmpty = NO;
NSMutableArray *sectionOne = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *sectionTwo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSArray *result = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
for (Tape *tape in result) {
    if ( tape.isEmpty.boolValue && !foundEmpty && tape.isTransparent.boolValue ) {
        // only include one isEmpty object
        [sectionOne addObject:tape];
        foundEmpty = YES;

    } else if ( tape.isEmpty.boolValue && !foundEmpty && !tape.isTransparent.boolValue ) {
        // only include one isEmpty object
        [sectionOne addObject:tape];
        foundEmpty = YES;

    } else if ( tape.isTransparent.boolValue && !tape.isEmpty.boolValue ) {
        // always include non-isEmpty objects
        [sectionOne addObject:tape];

    } else if ( !tape.isEmpty.boolValue ) {
        // always include non-isEmpty objects
        [sectionTwo addObject:tape];

    }
}

NSArray self.dataSource = @[sectionOnce, sectionTwo];
```

Comment: It isn't clear what your issue is. You want a section where the FRC may have multiple items but you want to display at most one?

Comment: @Wain - Added more detail. Thanks for asking for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below predicate

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(manufacturer = %@) AND (NOT (isTransparent = 0 AND isEmpty = 1)))", manufacturer];
```

The above code checks for isEmpty to be YES along with the manufacturer,

Comment: I added more details to the question based on Wain's comment. In the current predicate offered I believe this would return only those flagged as isEmpty; thereby, not including those NOT flagged as isEmpty. Is that correct; or, am I missing something.

Comment: @JoshBruce In your filtered result Delta tape is missing. So your condition is fetch tapes whose isEmpty is 0 when isTransparent is 0?

Comment: Updated answer based on ur description.

Comment: The reason Delta is missing is because it is marked with isEmpty = 1, and there is already one object with this property in the FRC (Gamma tape). Does that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, all you need to do is to add a little logic to the table delegate methods. Currently you will be returning the section row count from the FRC. Instead, for the appropriate section, return:

```
MIN(1, rowCountFromFRC)
```

such that if there are no rows, none will be shown, but if there are then a maximum of 1 will be shown.

Comment: This would always show only one row? See expanded example above.

Comment: What do you mean? This would show either one or zero rows.

Comment: In the example, it would show 3 rows, 2 sections, and one entity with isEmpty = 1...final table view example list...the current predicate would show 4 rows with 2 sections. Hope that helps clarify.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the predicate, it's entirely related to how many rows you tell the table to show. The fetch could return 100 items, but tell the table to show only 1 and it will...

Comment: I understand, but it's essentially not using the FRC results - at which point, the answer eludes to rolling my own array, which I'm wondering if I can avoid. Using this answer, I could say return 3 instead of 4, but could not guarantee the desired result.

Comment: Not even slightly, it 100% uses the FRC, hence the attribute name `rowCountFromFRC` which is a paraphrase of the section code to get the row count from the FRC. The sort descriptor guarantees the result.

Comment: Then can you expand your answer to demonstrate how the data set in the first list would result in the table view in the final example? For example, how would displayRow:atIndexPath work?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51687/discussion-between-wain-and-josh-bruce)

Comment: Will do. Thanks so far.